# Running java thread at a specific time only once for a specific duration and then stop

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to create a thread that will be executed at a specific time, for a specific duration and run only once and then stop until it get called again.

The problem is that whenever the thread is executed, it does not executed for the duration of time, it just prints one "Hi" and then stops immediately.
If I remove the flag, the thread will run forever.

```
  public void startExecutionAt(int targetHour, int targetMin, int duration)
    {
       log.info("Create thread!");
       Runnable taskWrapper= new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                if(runsFirst==true){
                    log.info("Thread inside!");
                    WateringScheduler.execute();
                    startExecutionAt(targetHour, targetMin, duration);
                }
                else{
                    log.info("Thread stoped!");
                    stop();
                    //close the led
                }
                runsFirst=false;
            }

        };

        long delay = computeNextDelay(targetHour, targetMin);
        System.out.println("Delay is : " + delay + " Duration is: " +duration);
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskWrapper, delay,duration, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


    private static long computeNextDelay(int targetHour, int targetMin) {
         LocalDateTime localNow = LocalDateTime.now();
         ZoneId currentZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
         ZonedDateTime zonedNow = ZonedDateTime.of(localNow, currentZone);          
         ZonedDateTime zonedNextTarget = zonedNow.withHour(targetHour).withMinute(targetMin);

        if (zonedNow.compareTo(zonedNextTarget) > 0) {
            zonedNextTarget = zonedNextTarget.plusDays(1);
        }

        Duration duration = Duration.between(zonedNow, zonedNextTarget);
        return duration.getSeconds();
    }


    public void stop()
    {
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          log.error("Error");;
        }
    }
    public static void execute(){
        System.out.println("Hi");
        //open the led;
    }
```

Comment: You are thinking in terms of JDK 1.0.  Have a look at the classes in java.util.concurrent: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Comment: @duffymo As far as I know ScheduledExecutorService is Java8...And that's what I am using.

Comment: What happens if the task isn't done in the allotted time?  Makes no sense.

Comment: @duffymo The problem is that when the thread runs for the duration time without the flag it will run forever.

Comment: Sounds like a bad design to me.

Comment: That's why I am asking for a little help. If I knew how to solve it by myself I wouldn't ask...Isn't that the purpose of stackoverflow?

Comment: Not always.  Maybe the problem is that you are convinced that this is the only way you can solve your problem.  More context might reveal another approach.  The problem is that you don't have that kind of control over threads in Java.  By design - they should be under the control of the operating system.

Comment: When you find yourself in a hole, stop digging.  You don't realize it, but I'm giving you some good advice.  You should rethink what you're doing.  Java is not meant to reproduce pre-emptive thread scheduling.  The OS does that.

Comment: Agreed. I'll try something different. Thanks again.

Comment: A possible way to control is a parent/manager thread. It creates a child thread, starts the child, keeps a reference to it, and invokes a stop method after the duration elapses. The controlling behaviour of start/stop is in the parent thread. I don't know how to control without the involvement of the parent thread. And this is pre-Executors, so perhaps not relevant to you.

Comment: @IanMc Hi, that's exactly what I wanted to do but I go confused with the Service Executor. I used ScheduledExecutorService wrong. I will update my answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got confused using the ScheduledExecutorService.

According to javadocs, "ScheduledFuture schedule creates and executes a one-shot action that becomes enabled after the given delay."

The code below executes the thread once and stops it after the (delay+duration)+1.

```
 public void startExecutionAt(int targetHour, int targetMin, int duration)
    {
       log.info("Create thread!");
       long delay = computeNextDelay(targetHour, targetMin);
       final Runnable executeR = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            execute();
                        }catch(Exception ex) {
                              log.error("Error in thread" + ex.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
       };

       final ScheduledFuture<?> executeHandler = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(executeR,delay, duration, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       executorService.schedule(
          new Runnable() {
           public void run() { 
               log.info("Thread is stopping");
               executeHandler.cancel(true); 
           }
         }, delay+duration+1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       System.out.println("Delay is : " + delay + " Duration is: " +duration);
        log.info("Thread out");
    }


    private static long computeNextDelay(int targetHour, int targetMin) {
         LocalDateTime localNow = LocalDateTime.now();
         ZoneId currentZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
         ZonedDateTime zonedNow = ZonedDateTime.of(localNow, currentZone);          
         ZonedDateTime zonedNextTarget = zonedNow.withHour(targetHour).withMinute(targetMin);

        if (zonedNow.compareTo(zonedNextTarget) > 0) {
            zonedNextTarget = zonedNextTarget.plusDays(1);
        }

        Duration duration = Duration.between(zonedNow, zonedNextTarget);
        return duration.getSeconds();
    }


    public void stop()
    {
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          log.error("Error");;
        }
    }
```